# Continuously getting "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" for my dataframe code

Tags: python, dataframe

I have been extracting leaf angles from 2D images and placing them inside a dataframe. I don't understand why I keep getting a "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" for the code. I ran it twice and it worked but then it started giving me this error.

```
idx = list(df.keys())
values = list(df.values())

cols = [[], [], [], []]

for id, x in enumerate(values):

    for i in range(4):
    
        if len(values[id]) <= i:
            cols[i].append('NaN')
        
        else:
            cols[i].append(values[id][i])

newDf = zip(idx, col1, col2, col3, col4)
newDf = pd.DataFrame(newDf, columns = ['PlantName', 'Leaf1', 
'Leaf2','Leaf3','Leaf4'])
newDf.set_index('PlantName',inplace=True)
#Median values for the first four
newDf['Median1to4'] = newDf.median(axis = 1)

newDf
```

This is the full error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_6988/3872441964.py in <module>
     48 
     49 idx = list(df.keys())
---> 50 values = list(df.values())
     51 
     52 cols = [[], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with line 50. It should be

```
values = list(df.values)
```

According to [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), they recommend using `.to_numpy()` instead:

```
values = df.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

if `df` is a pandas dataframe. it's `df.values` not `df.values()` . A `callable`  in Python just means `()` will `call` a function. Hence the error message `xxxxxx object is not callable`.